# How to create soap service using GET method

Tags: spring, web-services, soap

I'm beginner to the soap web service. When I create soap service don't think about That service is **POST** or **GET** .But when we create REST service we initialize that service is **POST** or **GET**.

I created soap web service.Here is my code

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://service.test.hameedia.com/", portName = "HameediaTestServicePort", serviceName = "HameediaTestServiceService")

public class SoapServiceTest{

     public String details(String name){
        //some thing in here
     }
}
```

But in here we didn't initialize this is **POST** or **GET** .But console show this is **POST** method.My question is

> Is soap web services default method type **POST**

If is it not

> How to create soap web service with **GET** method

I get some idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339317/does-soap-web-services-support-only-post-http-method).But I'm not clear with my question.If you have any idea about this please share.

Comment: Due to the nature and complexity of the content it is POST only. With GET you can only encode the URL which isn't suitable for SOAP. So although you might be able to get it to work for simple calls (does that exist in SOAP?) generally it will never work.

Comment: Thank you M.Deinum

Answer (score 1):

> SOAP is an acronym for Simple Object Access Protocol. It is an XML-based messaging protocol for exchanging information among computers. SOAP is an application of the XML specification.

SOAP is not depended upon HTTP and HTTP Method(s), SOAP can extend HTTP for XML messaging.

You can call SOAP Web Service over HTTP and you have to use POST method only because of complex nature of the SOAP Request.

Ref : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/what_is_soap.htm

Comment: Thank you Avinash. What is that complex nature. Do you have any idea or some reference.

Comment: Please search google and understand SOAP. SOAP cannot be compared to Rest API directly. You will automatically understand what complexcity I am talking about.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I got some idea about that using this.https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipgetr/