# Consume SOAP webservice with GET instead of POST

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap, http-get

I need to call an external SOAP webservice over HTTP.
I have the WSDL file and added it in Visual Studio via 'Add service reference'. Visual studio then added a number of files, in the reference file i can find this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="Service.IService")]
public interface IService {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/Function", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/FunctionResponse")]
    namespace.Service.ExecuteFunctionResponse ExecuteFunction(namespace.Service.FunctionRequest request);
}
```

With additionaly the async version of this call and the objects for sending an receiving, etc.

To call the service I added the folowing code:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();     
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("the address");
serviceChannel = new ServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress).ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
Response response = serviceChannel.ExecuteFunction(new Request(...));
```

This results in me getting an exception, error 405 method not allowed.
So it appears I must use a HTTP GET request instead of the default POST request. But i cannot find where this can be altered in with this way of working.

So, where can i set the HTTP method for this call to a webservice?

Comment: SOAP is very much discontinued. You should probably look to upgrade this to web api or WCF

Comment: It's a third party service, so there isn't much i can do about it I'm afraid.

Comment: Might explain you lack of responses though. I've not used SOAP for about 8 years, I used to know it well but...well that was 8 years ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP services are using HTTP POST because they exchange XML messages (which tend to be complex) and cannot be transferred in a query string.

Are you sure that you must use HTTP GET? Maybe the error you are receiving "405 method not allowed" is caused by some bad configuration.
I would double check the SOAP endpoint URL is set correctly and check that there are no additional security requirements needed.

**EDIT**
In past, there was a practice to create ASP.NET Web Services which would accept GET as well. But they wouldn't expect XML messages. Instead, you would have to pass all parameters in a querystring. For example: `https://foo.bar/service.asmx/Func?param1=X&param2=Y` (where param1 and param2 are the expected parameters).

This way it is possible to call a WebService without a need for WSDL and using GET method. You can achieve it by using HttpClient for example.
The downside of this approach is that you will have to deal with plain data instead of objects.

I hope it might help.

Comment: I looked it up before and according to other questions on here it is rare and usually not done, but possible and supported by the w3c standards. source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339317/do-soap-web-services-support-only-post-http-method

The data to send is rather limited and the example they gave of calling their service was a single URL. 
Upon looking in the wsdl though, it is a SOAP service. so I'm confused about the whole thing.

I think i'll take your advice though and contact the owners of the service and hear if something might be wrong in the config.

Comment: The method you put in the edit did the trick. Strange how I'm supposed to ignore the whole SOAP part, but if it works...  I'll award the bounty when it allows me in a few hours.

Comment: @kyudosai You are right. When using it in such way it isn't really SOAP (No XML). It is more like REST. I've encountered this with ASP.NET only. I'm glad I helped you :)

Comment: Are you sure ALL SOAP services are POST-based? I'm consuming a service which doesn't mention "POST" an option in it's WSDL. My POST methods fail with it.

Comment: @johnywhy Theoretically SOAP could be implemented in GET but as XML messages tend to be complex and verbose, it is impractical and personally, I never encountered such implementation. Could you share more information? stacktrace, error message?

Comment: @romanratiner Turned out i had was to change my "Content-Type" header from:
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8`. Using `MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest` with `POST`.