# Oracle Service Bus error: ClassCastException: CountingRequestWrapper cannot be cast to ServletRequestImpl

Tags: weblogic12c, osb

I developed a service for Oracle Service Bus and deployed on a WebLogic 12c server. The proxy service uses an HTTP adapter so that the service can be called using SOAP. The business service uses a REST adapter.

The service works fine when I test it on the integrated server or on my UAT server (which is WebLogic 12c) using the test page that's invoked from the ServiceBus console. Also tried using SOAPUI tool on two different Windows PC's.

However, when the third party invokes my service, I get an exception in my log. I added alerts and logs in my pipeline but neither of them get invoked meaning the exception happens in WebLogic before it can pass the request to my adapter.

Googling for "CountingRequestWrapper" gives zero results. I really can't figure out what is causing this.

Here's the log:

```
module:/MyApp/MyService path:null spec-version:3.1], request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@35881271[
GET /MyApp/MyService?wsdl HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
Accept: /
Connection: Keep-Alive

]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.http.wls.CountingRequestWrapper cannot be cast to weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl
        at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.http.wls.HttpTransportServlet.service(HttpTransportServlet.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.FutureResponseServlet.service(FutureResponseServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
```

I did notice that at the top it says: path: null. Could it be something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Request from log looks like a GET to wsdl address (GET /MyApp/MyService?wsdl) and you mentioned it's a soap proxy so that should most likely be a POST to service endpoint address. I would suggest to check 3rd party client side configuration first.

Comment: Yes, that rankled with me as well. A SOAP call must be POST in order to carry the payload. Unfortunately, client is using a third-party app and is not conversant in programming matters. They just know the bare minimum to run their app. Shall try asking them again.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339317/do-soap-web-services-support-only-post-http-method SOAP can be called using GET. That's a new one on me.

Comment: Update: As per client, they did not send a service request, rather they sent a service discover request, hence the GET method. Such a request should get a response with the wsdl. Calling it from a browser or Postman/SoapUI does show me the wsdl. Now, the question is as to why this generates the exception when sent by client's app.

Comment: "Accept: /" header from your log looks odd, can you force it in postman and try to reproduce the issue when grabbing the wsdl?

Comment: There should be asterisks there: Accept */*. I guess they got dropped somewhere during copy/pasting. I've tried every combination that I could think off in Postman and SoapUI but nothing I do generates that exception. Edit: I typed asterisks in the comment, but they disappear also. ````*/*````

Comment: I was finally able to replicate the exception. In the GET request there must be a Content-Length header, even if the RFC says it's optional. Exception occurs if I remove this from Postman. If I add it manually and set it to zero, works fine. Now... what to do about it...