# SOAP with Groovy script answers with 'ERROR' while PUT

Tags: groovy, soap, soapui

I have two same paths in my SOAP project, both of them use the same script

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class Response {
    Integer code
    String message
    String accountId
}

// Match based on body
try {
    def requestBody = mockRequest.getRequestContent()
    def requestJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(requestBody)
    def phone = requestJson.phone as String
    def email = requestJson.email as String
    def accountId = requestJson.accountId as String
    def response
    if (phone == null || phone == "") {
        response = new Response(code: 1011, message: 'Field phone is required')
    } else if (phone == "+79777777777") {
        response = new Response(code: 1021, message: 'The phone field must be in the format +79991112233')
    } else if (email == "testt@testt.com") {
        response = new Response(code: 1022, message: 'The email field must be in the format test@test.com')
    } else {
        response = new Response(code: 0, message: 'Success', accountId: accountId)
    }
    requestContext.response = JsonOutput.toJson(response).toString()
    return "response"
} catch (Exception ex) {
    requestContext.response = JsonOutput.toJson(new Response(code: 500, message: 'Emulator error: ' + ex.message)).toString()
    return "response"
}
```

My problem is in sending a request to `PUT` method with the script. The request is

```json
{
    "phone":"+79987654125",
    "email":"test@notify1.com",
    "accountId":"12345"
}
```

If I send `POST`, everything is okay

```json
{
    "message": "Success",
    "code": 0,
    "accountId": "12345"
}
```

If I send `PUT`, in a response I will see

```json
{
    "message": "Emulator error: Text must not be null or empty",
    "code": 500,
    "accountId": null
}
```

From the logs I see that the `PUT` script got `requestContext` as 'null'. What can be a problem?

Comment: How is this related to the tool [tag:soapui]?

Comment: Do you know, that SOAP usually only provides POST requests?
E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646146/http-soap-get-post